# Type patterns in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell

I'm trying to compile a simple example of generic classes / type patterns (see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/generic-classes.html) in Haskell but it won't compile. Any ideas about what's wrong with the code would be helpful.

According to the documentation there should be a module `Generics` with the data types `Unit`, `:*:`, and `:+:` but ghc (6.12.1) complaints about `Not in scope: data constructor 'Unit'` etc.

It seems like there's a package instant-generics with the data types `:*:`, `:+:` and `U` but when I import that module (instead of `Generics`) I get the error

```
Illegal type pattern in the generic bindings
    {myPrint _ = ""}
```

The complete source code is

```
import Generics.Instant

class MyPrint a where
  myPrint :: a -> String

  myPrint {| U |} _ = "" 
  myPrint {| a :*: b |} (x :*: y) = "" (show x) ++ ":*:" ++ (show y)
  myPrint {| a :+: b |} _ = ""


data Foo = Foo String

instance MyPrint a => MyPrint a

main = myPrint $ Foo "hi"
```

and I compile it using

```
ghc --make Foo.hs -fglasgow-exts -XGenerics -XUndecidableInstances
```

P.S. The module `Generics` export no data types, only the functions:

```
canDoGenerics
mkGenericRhs
mkTyConGenericBinds
validGenericInstanceType
validGenericMethodType
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I don't know that much about generics, but the symbols you're looking for are in the `Data.Generics` module, so I did

```
import Data.Generics
```

Second, the line

```
myPrint {| a :*: b |} (x :*: y) = "" (show x) ++ ":*:" ++ (show y)
```

has two problems: first, the "" is obviously too much. Second, you can't use `show` as the types used are not necessarily instances of the `Show` typeclass. So I made this line

```
myPrint {| a :*: b |} (x :*: y) = (myPrint x) ++ ":*:" ++ (myPrint y)
```

Finally, with

```
instance MyPrint a => MyPrint a
```

you first require that `a` is an instance of `MyPrint` and then you ask the compiler to derive a `MyPrint` instance for `a` that you required to already exist. This works for me:

```
instance MyPrint Foo
```

However, you have to manually provide an instance for `String` first so that the compiler has a starting point for derivation:

```
instance MyPrint String where
  myPrint s = s
```

Hope that helps.